# how to open html file in browser when nodeJs is running

Tags: html, css, node.js, authentication, axios

Hi I design a simple html login page. I simply open Html file by double click on it . but my issue is that I don't want to open it directly .I want to test it on correct address so after successfully login I want to open my home page
I use code bellow :

```
window.location.assign("/homeIndex.html");
```

Comment: for clear my request I should ask how to open my html simple login page on special address and not open it directly and how to change between pages .

Comment: Does http://localhost:3000 work?

Comment: my api is on address: localhost:3001/api/student/login .and it work correctly with post man . and my front page is work correctly when I Login and see the console but unfortunately  do not know the address setting to open my Login page on it

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: my ide is vscode

Comment: My problem is that go to my hard drive :e /.... and open login form .but my login form should not open from my hard and the address of it must like my api address so I can change between the pages.

Comment: My understanding is that if you run http://localhost:3000 the page is loading correctly. Is this true?

Comment: no it does not load on localhost:3000 :(

Comment: Have you started your NodeJS server?

Comment: yes I have started it . If I use plugin do you think is that correct ?

Comment: What port is it using?

Comment: I set to 3001 and test localhost:3001/api/student/login with no success !

Comment: I start learn front and I pass first steps :)